# Convert Community user to Portal user

Tags: customer-community, partner-communities, userlicense

We already *have a Custom Community* used by one of our clients. Now we are going to extend community functionality which requires ability to share records (Sharing Sets not an option in our case)

With that being said we need to change a License of our Customer Community users *to Partner Community*. But, this is impossible to chose other license on Community User.

Technically we can create another user, but it suppose to be a pain:

1. new password, that will confuse end user
2. moving all historical data (with LastModifiedDate changes)

**Any advice is welcome, how to turn Customer to Partner easily?**